# Is it possible to run networking commands like nmap in WSL?

Tags: networking, windows-10, bash, windows-10-v1607, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I recently got the Windows 10 anniversary update and installed bash. I tried installing nmap, but it wouldn't run.

My question: Is there any way for commands like nmap to correctly run in WSL?

Thanks in advance!

Error I get when running `sudo nmap -sn 192.168.1.*`: `route_dst_netlink: cannot bind AF_NETLINK socket: Invalid argument`

I remember reading somewhere that WSL doesn't have support for sockets, but can use TCP. Is this possible in this case? Also, will WSL ever have support for sockets?

Comment: Nmap is fully supported as a [native Windows application](https://nmap.org/download.html#windows). No need to use WSL.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, according to this thread: https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/69 the network options to support nmap are currently not all implemented.

Comment: Latest info is here: https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/1349