# Couldn't open a raw socket. Error: Permission denied (13) (nmap)

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, nmap

I'm using nmap in windows Subsystem for Linux. Why isn't nmap scanning anything? I'm using the link scanme.nmap.org to scan. I was testing nmap to see if it works, but it didn't even initialize. It just gave this error message:

[image]

I read [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1110625/is-it-possible-to-run-networking-commands-like-nmap-in-wsl) question, but it didn't really help.

Comment: Your query is same as that question you've linked. Raw sockets isn't supported now. See the GitHub issue in that Q&A.

Comment: @Biswapriyo But the linked provided in that answer didn't give a conclusion, so if raw sockets are not supported now, what should I do to make it work?

Comment: So I have to use it in VM only for now, untill it is made to be supported?

Comment: Why VM, nmap has a Windows version.

Comment: Oh, that's a good idea I think, thanks for notifying!

Comment: @Biswapriyo Yeah! Can mark it!